# Kubernetes changes content type

Tags: php, kubernetes, content-type, silex, guzzle

I have a service in PHP.
One endpoint calls to other endpoint in these service.
For connection I use guzzle.
Content sent from 1st endpoint to 2nd should be application/json.
On docker it works correctly but when I deploy to Kubernetes,
in logs I see that request content is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Even if content type is hardcoded:

```
private function getPostRequestOptions($postData) : array
{
    return [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Request-ID' => $this->requestId
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($postData),
        'connect_timeout' => static::CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
        'timeout' => static::TIMEOUT,
        'http_errors' => true,
    ];
}

public function sendPost(string $path, $postData): \stdClass
{
    return $this->executeRequest(
        'POST',
        $this->getFullUrl($path),
        $this->getPostRequestOptions(
            $postData
        )
    );
}
```

Does someone have any clue why it happens like this?

Comment: How are you connecting the two applications? Are you using Pod IP addresses? Kubernetes services? The proxy in the apiserver? I would expect only the last one to have any effect on http headers (since it's an http proxy). The first two are L3 connections and should not affect your application specific content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Dynatrace monitoring for php 7.
New version of plugin stopped cutting headers.